# Debug Vast advertising tags in JWplayer 7+

Tags: jwplayer, vast, preroll

Apparently because I am new here I cannot even post sufficent links to explain my problem fully. FYI

**Source**

mp4stream.com /
preroll /
videe /

This is one of many demos I have setup for various Ad Networks. Almost all have the same result.

**Part One**

A lot of the Ad Networks I demo all have the same issue that looks something like this. I'm talking at least 10 partners I've tested have. Below is an example of one.

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://vast.videe.tv/vast-proxy/?VPAID=1&aid=12988&sid=0&channel_id=0&conte…player_width=657&player_height=370&vid_duration=1440&cb=685997865628451100. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://mp4stream.com' is therefore not allowed access.*

These failures create a huge increase load time and affects the entire player /  user experience as a whole.

One Ad Network today indicated that I may be passing cookies to them and that is why the above is failing. But I have a hard time believing that based on my development / server experience. As far as I'm aware every single player JWplayer or otherwise would use cookies of some kind.

So the question I have is why do hundreds of these simply fail?

Answer (score 0):

to be servable in a JavaScript environment a VAST ad server’s response must include the following HTTP CORS headers:

**Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true**

This HTTP header allows an ads player on any origin to read the VAST response from the ad server origin. The value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin: should be the value of the Origin header sent with the ad request. The Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: header will ensure that cookies will be sent and received properly.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes, the above is confirmed.

Comment: Ugh, I hate how when you press enter here it saves the response. Anyway, yes the above is accurate. The question remains however that Allow-Origin cannot be a wildcard when Allow Creds is set to true. Which is why the requests are failing.

Comment: A wildcard * cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://mp4stream.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Yet, when I test the tag provided by JWplayer as a test the response in curl -i shows that they are using the wildcard and allow-credentials = true (yet somehow their test tags load a preroll impression) which all of the Ad Partners I work with have the same CORS response yet fail.

Answer (score 0):

Based on that error you are seeing,  vast.videe.tv is blocking mp4stream.com from making requests. You will need to contact videe.tv to determine why this is happening.

Here's a specific support document we have for this: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403679-crossdomain-file-loading

We love StackOverflow, but we don't check here often. The best way to get support for JW Player is to go to http://jwplayer.com/support/

Comment: jwplayer support is useless, sorry I just get the run around and it takes days for a respone, i've managed to get this far with the help of others who have also had to figure things out on their own

Comment: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/14468085-re-difficult-time-with-jwplayer-and-ads-implimentation

Comment: Feel free to follow up the above link. It does not look like Videe is specifically blocking mp4stream.com because when that occurs the result is a simple 403 and even displays in console.

Comment: However, it is blocking mp4stream.com because it is a known fact that when using CORS you cannot use a wildcard when Access Credentials are set to true.